# C# Regex Split - everything inside square brackets

Tags: c#, regex, split

I'm currently trying to split a string in C# (latest .NET and Visual Studio 2008), in order to retrieve everything that's inside square brackets and discard the remaining text.

E.g.: *"H1-receptor antagonist [HSA:3269] [PATH:hsa04080(3269)]"*

In this case, I'm interested in getting "**HSA:3269**" and "**PATH:hsa04080(3269)**" into an array of strings.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`Split` won't help you here; you need to use regular expressions:

```
// using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
// pattern = any number of arbitrary characters between square brackets.
var pattern = @"\[(.*?)\]";
var query = "H1-receptor antagonist [HSA:3269] [PATH:hsa04080(3269)]";
var matches = Regex.Matches(query, pattern);

foreach (Match m in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
}
```

Yields your results.

Comment: Do you find it awkward in 3.5 that MatchCollection enumeartor still returns Match as Object?

Comment: anyway... a better regex match might be \[([^\]]*)\] so as to be on the safe side :-)

Comment: @chakrit: 1. Yes, but this cannot be changed for backwards compatibility reasons. Really a shame though. Microsoft should have the balls to do like Python 3: throw everything pre-2.0 out for good and introduce a breaking change. But this won't happen …

Comment: @chakrit: 2. This was indeed my first version (I usually always use explicit groups) but I reconsidered because that's wordier to express exactly the same pattern (for all practical purposes). There's really no risk here in using the more implicit character class along with a nongreedy quantifier.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Here I am getting this "[HSA:3269]"....what will be the Regex if I want "HSA:3269". Without square brackets?

Comment: @chakrit - Firstly, you need to escape the outer square brackets. Secondly, the results are the same anyway, so why do you say "on the safe side"?

Comment: Use LINQ to get the captures from Group 1:  `var results = Regex.Matches(query, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string mystr = "Hello my name is  {robert} and i live in  {florida}";

List<string> myvariables = new List<string>();
while (mystr.Contains("{"))
{
    myvariable.Add(mystr.Split('{', '}')[1]);
    mystr = mystr.Replace("{" + mystr.Split('{', '}')[1] + "}", "");
};
```

This way I will have an array which will contain robert and florida.

Comment: This code assumes that the brackets are always matched perfectly (you never have `}` before `{`, and you never have `{` twice in a row. It is also very inefficient because it splits the string many times needlessly. It would be much more efficient and robust to use Regex like the other answer does.