# Regex match pattern inside a wrapping pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I want match all phone numbers that are wrapped  between << and >> tags.
This regex for phone numbers:

```
0[2349]{1}\-[1-9]{1}[0-9]{6}
```

I tired to add  lookahead (and lookbehind) like `(?=(?:>>))` but this didn't work for me.

[DEMO](http://www.myregextester.com/?r=b7f9d57d)

Comment: Must this all be done with a single RegExp?  Couldn't you just get all the matches for `<<(.*?)>>` then search within them using your current RegExp?

Comment: @shivesh: how many wrapping pattern can there be in the input? Only one `<<...>>` section, or can there be multiple? If multiple, can they be nested?

Comment: Yes I prefer to have one regex.

Comment: @shivesh: you didn't answer the question. How many `<<...>>` sections can there be in the input? Can there be multiple? If so, can they be nested?

Comment: @ polygenelubricants, there can be any number of nested <<>>

Comment: @shivesh: if you can nest the `<<..>>` then you can't do this with regex. Or perhaps you can in .NET, but essentially there's a paranthesis balancing subproblem which isn't a regular language.

Comment: @shivesh: "I prefer to have on regex"..? I totally agree with gnarf. Using two regular expressions makes your solution trivial, simple and easy to maintain. Why on earth try to squeeze it down to one hellish regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to work ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/zY4gL)):

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?s)<<(?:(?!>>)(?:(0[2349]\-[1-9][0-9]{6})|.))*>>");
```

Each `<<...>>` section is a `Match`, and all phone numbers in that section will be captured in [`Group[1].Captures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capturecollection.aspx).

#### Related questions

- [Is there a regex flavor that allows me to count the number of repetitions matched by the * and + operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029127/is-there-a-regex-flavor-that-allows-me-to-count-the-number-of-repetitions-matched/)

---

#### How the pattern is constructed

First of all, I simplified your phone number pattern to:

```
0[2349]\-[1-9][0-9]{6}
```

That is, the `{1}` is superfluous, so they get thrown away (see [Using explicitly numbered repetition instead of question mark, star and plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032593/using-explicitly-numbered-repetition-instead-of-question-mark-star-and-plus)).

Then, let's try to match each `<<...>>` section. Let's start at:

```
(?s)<<((?!>>).)*>>
```

This will match each `<<..>>` section. The `.*` to capture the body is guarded by a negative lookahead `(?!>>)`, so that we don't go out of bound.

Then, instead of matching `.`, we give priority to matching your phone number instead. That is, we replace `.` with

```
(phonenumber|.)
```

Then I simply made some groups non-capturing, and the phone number captures to `\1` and that's pretty much it. The fact that .NET regex stores all captures made by a group in a single match took care of the rest.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<<0[2349]{1}\-[1-9]{1}[0-9]{6}>>
```

Comment: have you checked the demo? it's must support multi line and multi white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I placed a similar question some time ago, using brackets ([]) instead of <<>>:

[Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740642/c-regex-split-everything-inside-square-brackets)

This should really help
Cheers

Edit: It should support your demo no problem.

Comment: I think i have a different scenario, I need to match a pattern inside another pattern

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done with two regex patterns:

To identify the section:

```
<<.*>>
```

Use the second regex on the matches from the first:

```
0[2349]-[1-9]\d{6}
```

Remember to set dot to match new line.
I know it isn't exactly what you were asking, but it will work.

Comment: Is it possible to do it with just one regex?

Comment: @shivesh, as the accepted answer shows it is possible to do in one regex, but it also show the biggest problem with regex, they very easily become very unreadable and hard to maintain. Unless it is strictly necessary I usually spit it up into smaller, easier to understand patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I think gnarf's (and Arkain's) suggestion is very sensible – you don't have to use one regex to do all the work.

But, if you really want to use one hard-to-read unportable (works only in .Net, not in other regex engines) regex, here you go:

```
(?<=<<(?:>?[^>])*)0[2349]{1}\-[1-9]{1}[0-9]{6}(?=(?:<?[^<])*>>)
```

Comment: if I run regex 2 times on the input text isn't it less efficient than 1 regex?

Comment: Maybe, but most of the time, readability and maintainability is more important than some minor difference in efficiency.

Also, the lookaheads and lookbehids I used can be quite inefficient, so using two regexes may actually be faster too.