# C# RegEx to find values within a string

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to RegEx. I have a string like following. I want to get the values between [{# #}]

Ex: `"Employee name is [{#John#}], works for [{#ABC Bank#}], [{#Houston#}]"`

I would like to get the following values from the above string.

```
"John",
"ABC Bank",
"Houston"
```

Comment: You should take a look at [ask]

Comment: What are "#"? Numbers? Anything?

Comment: It's not the best writing ever, but it looks pretty clear to me that he wants to extract values between hashes on strings that looks like: '[{# EXTRACT_THIS  #}]' Regex might be one way of doing it

Comment: @anomeric No # is not number .

Comment: We have to know what # is. You can't expect anyone to write an expression to pull data from a string if we don't know what the rest of the string is

Comment: @anomeric.  '#' is just a character like '[' and '{' . Basically I am looking to extract text between [{#.....#}] .

Comment: If it is &"[" or "{" then we can work with that. You have to tell us what characters we're parsing between

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the solution [Regular Expression Groups in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375873/regular-expression-groups-in-c-sharp).
You can try this:

```
       string sentence = "Employee name is [{#john#}], works for [{#ABC BANK#}], 
        [{#Houston#}]";
        string pattern = @"\[\{\#(.*?)\#\}\]";

        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(sentence, pattern))
        {
            if (match.Success && match.Groups.Count > 0)
            {
                var text = match.Groups[1].Value;
                Console.WriteLine(text);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the solution and [awesome breakdown for matching patterns inside wrapping patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3069575/33969) you could try:

`\[\{\#(?<Text>(?:(?!\#\}\]).)*)\#\}\]`

Where `\[\{\#` is your escaped opening sequence of `[{#` and `\#\}\]` is the escaped closing sequence of `#}]`.

Your inner values are in the matching group named `Text`.

```
string strRegex = @"\[\{\#(?<Text>(?:(?!\#\}\]).)*)\#\}\]";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline);
string strTargetString = @"Employee name is [{#John#}], works for [{#ABC Bank#}], [{#Houston#}]";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    var text = myMatch.Groups["Text"].Value;

    // TODO: Do something with it.
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Test("the quick brown [{#fox#}] jumps over the lazy dog."));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static string Test(string str)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                return string.Empty;


            var result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, @".*\[{#", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Singleline);
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result, @"\#}].*", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Singleline);

            return result;

        }

    }
}
```