# Detect particular tokens in a string. C#

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a very large string (HTML) and in this HTML there is particular tokens where all of them starts with "#" and ends with "#"

Simple Eg

```
<html>
<body>
      <p>Hi #Name#, You should come and see this #PLACE# - From #SenderName#</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I need a code that will detect these tokens and will put it in a list.
0 - #Name#
1 - #Place#
2 - #SenderName#

I know that I can use Regex maybe, anyway have you got some ideas to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can use regular expressions.

```
string test = "Hi #Name#, You should come and see this #PLACE# - From #SenderName#";
Regex reg = new Regex(@"#\w+#");
foreach (Match match in reg.Matches(test))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

As you might have guessed \w denotes any alphanumeric character. The + denotes that it may appear 1 or more times. You can find more info here [msdn doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx) (for .Net 4. You'll find other versions there as well).

Answer (score 12):

You can try:

```
// using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
// pattern = any number of arbitrary characters between #.
var pattern = @"#(.*?)#";
var matches = Regex.Matches(htmlString, pattern);

foreach (Match m in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
}
```

Answer inspired in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740642/c-regex-split-everything-inside-square-brackets) SO question.

Comment: +1 yes - considered using the non-greedy .* match too; although should it be .+?

Comment: Will this fail to parse a text like this: `Hi #Name#where#PLACE# more text`, or have i misunderstood something regarding how RegEx works. It might not be a valid problem for OP either, so it's just for my own curiosity :)

Comment: Yes. I think will fail with `Hi #Name#where#PLACE# more text`.

Comment: See VladV's answer. It will actually work out fine. Then I learned something new today also :)

Answer (score 4):

A variant without `Regex` if you like:

```
var splitstring = myHtmlString.Split('#');
var tokens = new List<string>();
for( int i = 1; i < splitstring.Length; i+=2){
  tokens.Add(splitstring[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why a downvote on this? It will procuce the required results. I would appreciate a reason from the downvoter.

Comment: it works, i'll give it a +1 to make up for the person who loves regex too much.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, @"#\w+#"))
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.",  m.Value, m.Index);
```

Comment: How will this parse `Hi #Name#where#PLACE# more text` correctly. Doesn't this parse words "outside" the hashes also as long as it's a single word? Or are I mistaken here?

Comment: Just verified - on your example it gives "#Name#" and "#PLACE#".   When multiple matches are considered, each of them starts after the previous one ends - that is, after "#Name#" is matched, it starts looking for a next match after the second hash sign.

Comment: +1: That is perfect. I see why now, since the # is actually "used" by the first match, and therefore cannot be used by the second also. Thanks for the enlightment.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
var result = html.Split('#')
                    .Select((s, i) => new {s, i})
                    .Where(p => p.i%2 == 1)
                    .Select(t => t.s);
```

Explanation:

line1 - we split the text by the character '#'

line2 - we select a new anonymous type, which includes the strings position in the array, and the string itself

line3 - we filter the list of anonymous objects to those that have an odd index value - effectively picking 'every other' string - this fits in with finding those strings that were wrapped in the hash character, rather than those outside

line4 = we strip away the indexer, and return just the string from the anonymous type

Comment: +1 for using the `Select` overload that gives you the index in addition to the value that I think all are aware of.

Comment: Nice and short, but would you mind explaining it a bit further? s,i, p? perhaps use "explaining" variables would make it more educational for others.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(mytext, @"#(\w+)#");

foreach(Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Naive solution:

```
var result = Regex
    .Matches(html, @"\#([^\#.]*)\#")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Linq solution:

```
        string s = @"<p>Hi #Name#, 
          You should come and see this #PLACE# - From #SenderName#</p>";

        var result = s.Split('#').Where((x, y) => y % 2 != 0).Select(x => x);
```

Comment: Nice and short, but would you mind explaining it a bit further? x,y? perhaps use "explaining" variables would make it more educational for others.

Comment: @BerggreenDK Of course, the method `Where` is overloaded. `(x,y)` is a pair, where `x` is current item of the collection and `y` is the index of this item. Yes, your're right, I could have used `Where(item,index)` for better readability. After I choose only odd strings, because they are those we need.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Regex.Matches` method with a pattern of something like

`#[^#]+#` for the pattern.

Which is possibly the most naive way.

This might then need to be adjusted if you wish to avoid including the '#' characters in the output match, possibly with a lookaround:

`(?<=#)[^#]+(?=#)`

(A match value for this would be 'hello' not '#hello#' - so you don't have to do any more trimming)

Answer (score 0):

This gives you a list of the tokens as requested:

```
var tokens = new List<string>();
var matches = new Regex("(#.*?#)").Matches(html);

foreach (Match m in matches) 
    tokens.Add(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

**Edit:** If you *don't* want the pound characters included, just move them outside the parentheses in the Regex string (see Pablo's answer).