# Finding token in large string

Tags: c#, regex

Hi I need to find all matches in a large string, I found this question

[Detect particular tokens in a string. C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277567/detect-particular-tokens-in-a-string-c-sharp)

Which seemed perfect! Only problem it didn't work. The difference between that problem and mine is that instead of using #\w+# I need to use [[\w+]]. Here is the code I have (sb is my large string):

```
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"[[\w+]]");
        foreach (Match m in reg.Matches(sb.ToString()))
        {
            RenderHtmlRecursive(helper, sb, path, m.Value);
        }
```

When I run this I get 1 match :) but the value is (m.Value): "t]"

sb is (small text for now):  Card card [[RegisterText]]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[` and `]` are special characters used in Regular Expressions, and they need to be escaped if you wish to match that character.

Simply changing it to the following should work;

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"\[\[\w+\]\]");
```

Answer (score 3):

This would be an excellent opportunity to use a [DAFSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_acyclic_finite_state_automaton) which is a form of a Trie which has no payload. Efficient, O(n) lookup for phrases in large strings.

Answer (score -2):

You may considered named token in regex. For example
((?((POBox|PO\sBox)\s*\d*)),?\s?)?(((?([\w\d\s\,]*)),\s?)?( (?([\w\s-]*\w\s(st\s)?[\w]*\s(street|st|road|rd|close|cl|avenue|ave|av|path|ph|drive|drv|LOOP|COURT|CT|CIRCLE|LANE|LN)) ),?\s?))?((?([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lo}\p{Pc}\p{Lt}\p{Lm}\s]*)),?\s?)?((?(Victoria|VIC|New South Wales|NSW|South Australia|SA|Northern Territory|NT|West Australia|WA|Tasmania|TAS|ACT|Queensland|QLD))\s*)?(?(\d{4}),?\s?)?(?(Australia))?

for  28 Lidco Street, Arndell Park, Sydney 2148

To evaluate your regx expression, it is handy to use Expresso - A Tool for Building and Testing Regular Expressions at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3669/Expresso-A-Tool-for-Building-and-Testing-Regular-E

Comment: It is exceedingly unclear to me how your answer has anything at all to do with the OP's question aside from the fact that regexes are involved.