# Parse strings between delimiters into an array

Tags: vb.net, string, get

I have a string input something like this:

> [hellothere1241 fellow omg what][how many tiasf sgasgag][gas adgh adh sdgsd gsd][ gsdgsdgsdg sd sdgsdgsgsd ga21451t ][t13g1gsd s]

I need to get all the strings between each [ and ] to an array like that:

```
hellothere1241 fellow omg what
how many tiasf sgasgag
gas adgh adh sdgsd gsd
gsdgsdgsdg sd sdgsdgsgsd ga21451t
t13g1gsd s
```

Can anyone give me an example?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/740649/187697). The VB.NET equivalent would be

```
Dim pattern = "\[(.*?)\]"
Dim query = "[hellothere1241 fellow omg what][how many tiasf sgasgag][gas adgh adh sdgsd gsd][ gsdgsdgsdg sd sdgsdgsgsd ga21451t ][t13g1gsd s]"
Dim matches = Regex.Matches(query, pattern)
```